# What was the first game to show toilets?

Tags: gaming-history

And by "toilets" I mean the actual thing you sit on, not just "restrooms".

Not trying to be weird, I just remember I first saw them in Fallout 3 (2008) and suddenly realized those fixtures had been under-represented in video games. Which is understandable in the U.S., where most folks were uncomfortable with restroom stuff. But the Japanese are OK with it (e.g. [this](https://www.upi.com/Odd_News/2015/08/28/Japanese-kids-enter-giant-toilet-to-learn-about-poop/3511440773676/)) so I figure some of their old games must feature 'toe.ih.reh'.

Comment: Related Meta discussions: *[What is the difference between historical trivia questions and identification or recommendation questions? And should they be allowed?](//meta.arqade.com/questions/13431)*, *[Is "Historical Trivia" off-topic?](//meta.arqade.com/q/9818)*, and *["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](//meta.arqade.com/q/4491)*

Comment: *[Comments Flushed]* - We don't need to maintain a running comment-list of every video game toilet :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### (1983) *Manic Miner*

In *Manic Miner*, the toilets appear not as fixtures in an actual bathroom but as animated enemies on [level 5: Eugene's Lair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uph2Q00jCfU&t=262s). Its sequel, *Jet Set Willy* (1984), is probably the first to feature an actual bathroom with a toilet, but toilets first appeared a year early.

[image: Manic Miner screenshot]

**To those still upvoting:** scroll down to the better answers below!

Comment: Which of the sprites represent toilets?

Comment: @JacobKrall the black and orange ones in the top left quadrant

Comment: @JacobKrall: If you watch the linked video that still is from, it's perhaps more obvious that they are animated toilets flapping their lid (? or seat) as they move.

Comment: The father of a childhood friend of mine was the one time math's teacher of the game developer, Matthew Smith. I was told that 'Eugene' was based on my friend's Dad. Apparently, a few of the bad guys were based upon Smith's former teachers.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush Dare I ask why the level based on this teacher featured dangerous toilets? (Also, marvellously apt username for this question!)

Comment: @JackAidley Good question! I don't know sorry. I've not seen this friend for about 30 years so I can't answer that one.

Comment: @TannerSwett the black one looks more like a cat to me!

Answer (score 51):

#### (1980) Mystery House

Mystery House is the earliest so far, released by On-Line Systems; May 5th, 1980

[playable archive.org link](https://archive.org/details/Hi-Res_Adventure_1_Mystery_House_1980_On-Line_Systems) - [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10779428/?ref_=sr_t_11)

`U, OPEN DOOR, GO DOOR, U, N, N, GO DOOR, E` will get you there.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic find.

Comment: `SEARCH DEAD BODY`

Comment: Beats *Leisure Suit Larry* for showing a toilet in context, and *Can of Worms* for showing any sort of toilet.

Answer (score 32):

#### (1984) Jet Set Willy

This is the first one I can think of. The first level in the game starts you in The Bathroom:

[image: Jet Set Willy Bathroom]

Image from [World of Spectrum](https://worldofspectrum.org/archive/software/games/jet-set-willy-software-projects-ltd)

Comment: According to [this webpage](https://vgbathrooms.colum.edu) it seems like that game is the first one to have a toilet. Quot: *The first video game bathroom in Jet Set Willy (1984)*... I'm surprised there's a database for a videogame bathroom, really.

Comment: @Skye-AT that is a _very_ incomplete database.

Comment: @OrangeDog Indeed it seems to be incomplete, but what's the problem anyway? I never said it is *complete* database. I just said I am surprised to see that this database exists.

Comment: @Skye-AT it means its claims of "first" are suspect. It may be missing earlier ones, just as it is missing pretty notable later ones.

Comment: @OrangeDog Perhaps because the earlier one's toilet was enemy, so they didn't think that's suitable for their site? I mean, title of their site is Video game "bathroom" database, not video game *toilet* database.

Comment: What about the first one you can use and/or flush?    The first one I remember was Duke Nukem 3D which was in the early 90s (maybe 91) and you could pee, and even walk in on a monster sitting on a toilet...

Answer (score 25):

#### (1981) Can of Worms: Royal Flush

The *Can of Worms* games compendium for the ZX81 by Mel Croucher (of Pimania fame) was released in 1981.  It contained the game "Royal Flush" ("Unblock the Palace Sewer skillfully or it's Brown Alert").

An advert for the game can be seen on [page 62 of the November 1981 edition](https://archive.org/details/Computer_Video_Games_Issue_003_1982-01_EMAP_Publishing_GB/page/n61/mode/2up) of the magazine Computer and Video Games

Judging by the screenshot in the advert, there is a depiction of an unknown Royal sitting on a toilet.  Very low-res of course, but still meets the criteria of the question.

[image: Can of Worms 1981 screenshot]

Comment: Here is an actual [screenshot](https://www.digitiser2000.com/uploads/4/0/6/6/40667199/screen-shot-2019-08-14-at-09-19-45_orig.png) from the game

Comment: It can even be played here: https://www.zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/emulate.php?track=CanOfWorms.tzx.zip%405&title=Royal+Flush+from+Can+of+Worms (press R then enter) although I couldn't figure out how the game actually works (found instructions here: https://www.zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/inlays/c/CanOfWorms.Inside.jpg )

Comment: For those like me having trouble parsing the low-res image: The king is sitting facing left, hunched over; the `O` is his head, the `W` is his crown, the large black region is his body and legs.  The grey immediately below+behind him is the toilet + cistern, and the long grey line to the right is presumably the pipe/sewer.

Answer (score 20):

#### (1987) Leisure Suit Larry in the Land of the Lounge Lizards

Not the earliest of the 80s but pretty early on - *Leisure Suit Larry in the Land of the Lounge Lizards* had a bathroom:

[image: toilet in Leisure Suit Larry]

Answer (score 5):

#### (1985) Little Computer People

Honorable mention might go to *Little Computer People*, where the little person would actually use the toilet on occasion (which admittedly wasn't 100% visible, but could clearly be seen within the bathroom door).

[image: Screenshot of Little Computer People (1985)]

Comment: Oh, wow! I loved this game as a kid. Blast from the past!